# Replacement Of Sendkeys in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is there any replacement of `sendkeys` in `selenium` as we have in `Coded UI` `element.text`.

Answer (score 2):

See the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583641/set-value-of-input-instead-of-sendkeys-selenium-webdriver-nodejs). I think setting the value in the HTML source will be the only alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's not exactly a replacement but an alternative way to do it with the help of JavascriptExecutor Interface.

To add more, JavascriptExecutor interface is used to execute JavaScript with Selenium. In easy terms, think of it as a medium that enables the WebDriver to interact with HTML elements within the browser.

Append following code will help you.

```
dr.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
JavascriptExecutor j = (JavascriptExecutor)dr;
j.executeScript ("document.getElementById('search_query_top').value='Printed Dress'");
    WebElement wl = dr.findElement(By.name("submit_search"));
    wl.click();
```

Thanks and hope it has reached to your expectations.
Happy Automating :D